# Make IPython show source code line where exception occurred

Tags: python, debugging, exception, ipython

I'm irritated by the following output that IPython gives me for an exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4c27956d23f6> in <module>()
----> 1 parameterStudyPageRankNibble()

/Users/cls/Desktop/LFR/scripts/scd_experiments.py in parameterStudyPageRankNibble()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'
```

- A line number from where the exception was raised would be really
  helpful. Why isn't it there?
- `/Users/cls/Desktop/LFR/scripts/scd_experiments.py` is not the path of the script which is executed. IPython somehow mixed together
  the path of the script file and the current working directory.

What can I do to get more helpful information when an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how you load the code into IPython. (It would be helpful if you told us how to reproduce your problem.)
For example, if I use emacs's `M-x py-execute-region`, the region of code is copied to a temporary file and the IPython interpreter runs `execfile` on the temporary file.

When emacs/IPython is used in this manner, there is no useful traceback.

If instead, you import the script and then call the function:

```
import scd_experiments as SE
SE.parameterStudyPageRankNibble()
```

then you will see a useful traceback message.

---

Demo: script.py

```
def foo():
    1/0
```

If I select the region and call `M-x py-execute-region`,

```
In [15]: ## working on region in file /tmp/python-4126aNj.py...

In [16]: foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-624891b0d01a> in <module>()
----> 1 foo()

/tmp/python-4126aNj.py in foo()

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

But if I import the module:

```
In [19]: import script
In [20]: script.foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3ae0d96fd279> in <module>()
----> 1 script.foo()

/home/unutbu/pybin/script.py in foo()
      8 
      9 def foo():
---> 10     1/0

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: I imported the code with `from scd_experiments import *`. When I import with `import scd_experiments as exp`, I get line numbers for exceptions, but ONLY as long as I stay in the script directory. If I `cd` into the working directory, the problem reappears.

Comment: I believe the change of working directory is the problem. When I `cd` from the IPython prompt or from the script via `os.chdir`, I lose the line numbers.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the symptoms. Even when I use `from script import *` I get a useful traceback, and `cd-ing` does not affect this for me. I'm using IPython version 2.0.0-dev.

Comment: I'm using IPython 2.0.0.

Comment: Ah. I can reproduce the problem if (for me) `script.py` is not in a directory listed in my PYTHONPATH. So try adding the directory containing `scd_experiments` to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: If an error occurs, message should point to line number of source, otherwise it's a bug. Please report them at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 0):

WRT answer by unutbu:

python-mode.el should not say just "module", but display the name of the buffer or file called, something seems broken:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1318991

Also must read imports by default when executing source,
no explicit setting of PYTHONPATH required here.

It might be worth mentioning in context:

py-execute-... commands may use backends different from default according to options

- `python-mode-v5-behavior-p`
- `py-execute-no-temp-p`
- `py-fast-process-p`

python-mode.el v5 series used
`shell-command-on-region`. At that time existed bug
lp:550661, WRT unicode symbol u'\xA9', ©

That bug was avoided by running the stuff from a
temporary file. Which is the default still. An
error-message sent from Python than points to the
temporary file - which requires to be dealt with at the
Emacs side.

As a user wanted to stay with simpler old proceeding,
 `python-mode-v5-behavior-p` was provided as an option.

In order to speed up and/or execute on systems without
write-permission, a newer backend avoids writing
temporary files. Internally relies on
`process-send-string`. Customize `py-execute-no-temp-p`
to enable it.

With v6 series stuff is processed by an interactive
(I)Python shell. That allows further interactive
investigations. The backside was shown by lp:1253907 -
with large output, the comint bookkeeping might make
Emacs slow, resp. freeze.

Thus option `py-fast-process-p' was introduced - see
menu "Python/Fast process..." Avoids Python shell,
results arrive in buffer "*Python Output*".

With version 6.1.3, optional `py-fast-process-p` is not
released yet, available in trunk.

Comment: I assume it's a bug in IPython, but what does emacs have to do with it?

Comment: @cls An Emacs python-mode bug was displayed in answer of unutbu, as error should not point to the temporary file, but to original source.